# getting vectors to appear the same in R environment

Tags: r, vector, posixct

One vector is listed in the environment as:
 Large POSIXct (51183 elements)
The other vector is listed in the environment as:
 Class ‘POSIXct’ atomic [1:51183]

How can I make them listed as the same?  I want to be able to subtract one vector from the other, and I am hoping making them the same "type" will allow me to do this.

Thanks, I am new to R!

Here is example of the first vector
"1408430640", "1408430640", "1408430640", "1408430640", "1408430640", 
"1408430640" class = "POSIXct")
>

Here is an example of the second vector
1351958400, 1351958400, 1351785600, 1351872000, NA, 1378213200,class = "POSIXct", tzone = "")

Comment: You're referring to the *Environment* panel in RStudio I'm assuming? Also please provide a representative example of your data, e.g. using `dput`.